How to redirect all query string URLs of this type
I can't direct links followed by queries in PHP calls I would like to direct only some PHP pages
I have urls that call certain php pages and are followed by query strings,
https://hello.it/tr/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=rest-nonce
https://hello.it/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=likeboxfrontend&TB_iframe=true&width=500&height=438
I would like to redirect these URLs to the main page of the site to delete them.
I usually use this rule to create the query redirect and it works
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /?paged=(.)=catelog_shop&id(.)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
but if I add the example url it doesn't work anymore.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\admin-ajax.php?action=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
The point is that I want to create the redirect only for admin-ajax.php pages that have a query call.
This rule for index.php example works
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\index.php?s=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
but on other pages PHP does not work
